# Protocol Violation error and OALL8 is in an inconsistent state

Tags: oracle11g

I have been getting this error in my application intermittently..I checked it online ane most of the post says its incompatibility between jdbc driver and oracle version. The oracle version is 11.2.0.4.0 and i checked the oracle website and downlaoded the ojdbc6 driver and comapred it with the one we are using in application. Both drivers are same. so its not compatibility issue.
Can anyone please help with this issue?

Please find the logs below:

```
    org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not load an entity: [com.abc.xyz.model.train#component[trainNumber,depCityCode,arrCityCode,trainOrgDate,trainCode]{trainOrgDate=Wed Feb 17 00:00:00 CST 2016, depCityCode=MEM, arrCityCode=DFW, trainNumber=2177, trainCode=AA}]; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select train0_.trainNumber as trainNu1_1_0_, train0_.dep_citycode as dep2_1_0_, train0_.arr_citycode as arr3_1_0_, train0_.train_org_date as train4_1_0_, train0_.train_code as train5_1_0_, train0_.last_update_time as last6_1_0_, train0_.downline_station as downline7_1_0_, train0_.actual_train as actual8_1_0_, train0_.dep_date as dep9_1_0_, train0_.local_dep_date as local10_1_0_, train0_.schd_dep_time as schd11_1_0_, train0_.schd_arr_time as schd12_1_0_, train0_.est_dep_time as est13_1_0_, train0_.est_arr_time as est14_1_0_, train0_.actual_dep_time as actual15_1_0_, train0_.actual_arr_time as actual16_1_0_, train0_.arr_gate as arr17_1_0_, train0_.dep_gate as dep18_1_0_, train0_.arr_terminal as arr19_1_0_, train0_.dep_terminal as dep20_1_0_, train0_.tail_number as tail21_1_0_, train0_.aircraft_type as aircraft22_1_0_, train0_.leg_status as leg23_1_0_, train0_.dep_status as dep24_1_0_, train0_.arr_status as arr25_1_0_, train0_.dep_gmt_adjustment as dep26_1_0_, train0_.arr_gmt_adjustment as arr27_1_0_, train0_.bag_claim as bag28_1_0_, train0_.int_dom as int29_1_0_, train0_.diverted_citycode as diverted30_1_0_, train0_.prev_gate_active as prev31_1_0_, train0_.ds_dep_status as ds32_1_0_, train0_.ds_arr_status as ds33_1_0_, train0_.prev_dep_gate as prev34_1_0_, train0_.is_oag as is35_1_0_, train0_.fh_timestamp as fh36_1_0_, train0_.etd_update_timestamp as etd37_1_0_, train0_.eta_update_timestamp as eta38_1_0_, train0_.on_update_timestamp as on39_1_0_, train0_.in_update_timestamp as in40_1_0_, train0_.off_update_timestamp as off41_1_0_, train0_.eto_update_timestamp as eto42_1_0_, train0_.out_update_timestamp as out43_1_0_, train0_.cancel_update_timestamp as cancel44_1_0_, train0_.eqsub_update_timestamp as eqsub45_1_0_, train0_.gate_update_timestamp as gate46_1_0_, train0_.create_update_timestamp as create47_1_0_, train0_.cycle_update_timestamp as cycle48_1_0_, train0_.delete_update_timestamp as delete49_1_0_, train0_.reinstate_update_timestamp as reinstate50_1_0_, train0_.schd_dep_gmt_timestamp as schd51_1_0_, train0_.schd_arr_gmt_timestamp as schd52_1_0_, train0_.schd_dep_loc_timestamp as schd53_1_0_, train0_.schd_arr_loc_timestamp as schd54_1_0_, train0_.est_dep_gmt_timestamp as est55_1_0_, train0_.est_dep_loc_timestamp as est56_1_0_, train0_.est_arr_gmt_timestamp as est57_1_0_, train0_.est_arr_loc_timestamp as est58_1_0_, train0_.actual_on_gmt_timestamp as actual59_1_0_, train0_.actual_on_loc_timestamp as actual60_1_0_, train0_.actual_in_gmt_timestamp as actual61_1_0_, train0_.actual_in_loc_timestamp as actual62_1_0_, train0_.psgrload_update_timestamp as psgrload63_1_0_, train0_.diversion_update_timestamp as diversion64_1_0_, train0_.continuation_update_timestamp as continu65_1_0_, train0_.rtd_update_timestamp as rtd66_1_0_, train0_.actual_out_gmt_timestamp as actual67_1_0_, train0_.actual_out_loc_timestamp as actual68_1_0_, train0_.reg_nbr as reg69_1_0_, train0_.train_key as train70_1_0_, train0_.dep_gmt_adjustment_offset as dep71_1_0_, train0_.arr_gmt_adjustment_offset as arr72_1_0_, train0_.NEXT_train_NUMBER as NEXT73_1_0_, train0_.NEXT_train_DATE as NEXT74_1_0_, train0_.PREV_train_KEY as PREV75_1_0_ from train train0_ where train0_.trainNumber=? and train0_.dep_citycode=? and train0_.arr_citycode=? and train0_.train_org_date=? and train0_.train_code=?]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17401]; Protocol violation; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:512)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:506)
at com.abc.xyz.model.dao.trainDAOImpl.retrievetrain(trainDAOImpl.java:37)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.service.infoHubServiceImpl.processtrainEvent(infoHubServiceImpl.java:97)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor300.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.processtrainEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:251)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.processEvent(eventConsumer.java:257)
at com.abc.xyz.plugin.infoHub.eventConsumer.onMessage(eventConsumer.java:83)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:561)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:499)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1059)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1051)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:948)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:796)
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: OALL8 is in an inconsistent state
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshal(T4C8Oall.java:474)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:180)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:92)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3268)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$1.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:519)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
... 207 more
```

Comment: Hi Deejay, did not find any solution for the problem? We are also facing same problem.Drivers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

If upgrading the driver is doable then I suggest you use the latest driver - as of today it's 12.1.0.2 - against your 11.2.0.4 server. In the 12.1.0.2 version of the driver the `SQLException: OALL8 is in an inconsistent state` exception no longer exists. Issues in the protocol have been resolved so the chances that your issue will not reproduce are high. If after upgrading you still get this error then the next step it so contact Oracle Support because a protocol violation is bug.